# In Perl, what is the meaning of =()=

Tags: regex, perl, operators

Really simple question but the =()= operator (or operators) lets me count the matches in regex. What is this operator called and what exactly is it doing?

Example usage:

`my $count_quotes =()= $csv_line =~ /\"/gi;`

Thanks

Comment: Your question is covered in http://stackoverflow.com/q/3991766/133939 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/2897853/133939

Comment: Thanks Zaid, I had trouble searching for it and knowing the name is helpful now. I don't know why I got down voted as I asked a question because I didn't know or couldn't find the answer.

Comment: It's just a weird way or writing `my $count = () = ...;`. See [Mini-Tutorial: Scalar vs List Assignment Operator](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=790129)

Comment: The Perl secret operators are not so secret anymore as they have [some documentation on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/module/perlsecret)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FWIW, you could count the number of quotes with the `tr///` operator as well:

```
my $count = $csv_line =~ tr/"/"/;
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll mark it as accepted because it makes what the code is doing clear and understandable.